# Разрабатываю мобильное приложение под Android и при добавлении карт в приложение возникли следующие ошибки

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

[image: Ошибки]

```C#
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using RedBookTo;
using RedBookTo.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace RedBookTo.Droid
{
   public class CustomMapRenderer
    {
        CustomCircle circle;
        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                circle = formsMap.Circle;
                Control.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            var circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            circleOptions.InvokeCenter(new LatLng(circle.Position.Latitude, circle.Position.Longitude));
            circleOptions.InvokeRadius(circle.Radius);
            circleOptions.InvokeFillColor(0X66FF0000);
            circleOptions.InvokeStrokeColor(0X66FF0000);
            circleOptions.InvokeStrokeWidth(0);

            NativeMap.AddCircle(circleOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну так и что вы хотите?

Comment: Я хочу,чтобы мне помогли исправить эти самые ошибки

Comment: Возможно, что это просто моя вечерняя усталость, но ИМХО, не все что нужно для анализа Вашего класса, содержится в Вашем коде.

Comment: как именно? У вас текст ошибок написан, вы его читали? Сами что то пытались исправить?

Comment: Да,я пыталась сама исправить,но у меня не получилось

Comment: так покажите, как именно вы пытались исправить, покажите ваш код с исправлениями, поясните что конкретно не получилось? Никто не будет за вас править ваш код, вы расскажете и покажете нам ваши попытки, мы поможем вам понять, как вы сами можете ваш код исправить.